# How to do advanced MIDI keyboard routing?

Tags: sound, music, jack, midi

I want to replicate a specific model of e-piano on my MIDI keyboard. To do this, I must send white keys to one synth application, and black keys to shift down half a tone and send to another synth.
I have no idea how to accomplish it with JACK. Do I need to write specific app for this or is there anything already? Can somebody point me at where to start reading? Where to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting keys by *color* is so unusual that there is no software that can do this automatically.

You have to do some programming yourself, but there are MIDI filter platforms that make it easer, such as [mididings](http://das.nasophon.de/mididings/) or [midish](http://www.midish.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via GUI using  [QMIDIRoute](http://alsamodular.sourceforge.net/) but you'll have to set up a rule for at least each black key.